# How to use full PDF.js viewer with toolbar in webpack and Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2, pdf.js

I'm using a vue.js spa and webpack trying to show a PDF with mozilla's PDF.js. I got the [examples](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/) working pretty easily but i struggle to get the full viewer with the toolbar working. I am requiring PDFjs with `require('pdfjs-dist/webpack')` so it doesn't send the "a fake worker has been set up" warning. I can't really find an SO question/guide or video that explains how to use the full viewer with webpack. The Documentation of this project is nearly non-existent either and i think i tried every bit i could find there, too.

Sorry if this seems like a stupid question, but I struggle with it big time and clicked every link i could find with google searches.

Thanks in advance guys

the code that i already have from the examples:

```
var PDFJS = require('pdfjs-dist/webpack');

  const url = 'the-url-to-my-pdf';
  const canvasContainer = document.getElementById('preview');

  function renderPage(page) {
    const viewport = page.getViewport(2);
    let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    let canvasWrapper = document.createElement('div');
    canvasWrapper.classList.add('page');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const renderContext = {
      canvasContext: ctx,
      viewport: viewport
    };
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;
    canvasWrapper.appendChild(canvas);
    canvasContainer.appendChild(canvasWrapper);

    page.render(renderContext);
  }

  function renderPages(pdfDoc) {
    for(var num = 1; num <= pdfDoc.numPages; num++) {
      pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(renderPage);
    }
  }

  PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(renderPages);
```

the element 'preview' is just a wrapper div for multiple pdf pages

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @UtkarshPramodGupta I did, but what exactly is the problem with my question? Sry, I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Read it again from top to bottom and line by line. You'll find the problem yourself. :)

Comment: i added my code to the question, even though i said that i almost completely copy-pasted it from the examples, maybe that is what you wanted? i can't find anything else. Please tell me what i could improve in particular, in case the question is still badly described

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a full example - complete single-file Vue component:

```
<template>
  <div class="pdfjs">
    <div id="outerContainer">

      <div id="sidebarContainer">
        <div id="toolbarSidebar">
          <div class="splitToolbarButton toggled">
            <button id="viewThumbnail" class="toolbarButton group toggled" title="Show Thumbnails" tabindex="2" data-l10n-id="thumbs">
              <span data-l10n-id="thumbs_label">Thumbnails</span>
            </button>
            <button id="viewOutline" class="toolbarButton group" title="Show Document Outline (double-click to expand/collapse all items)" tabindex="3" data-l10n-id="document_outline">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_outline_label">Document Outline</span>
            </button>
            <button id="viewAttachments" class="toolbarButton group" title="Show Attachments" tabindex="4" data-l10n-id="attachments">
              <span data-l10n-id="attachments_label">Attachments</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="sidebarContent">
          <div id="thumbnailView">
          </div>
          <div id="outlineView" class="hidden">
          </div>
          <div id="attachmentsView" class="hidden">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  <!-- sidebarContainer -->

      <div id="mainContainer">
        <div class="findbar hidden doorHanger hiddenSmallView" id="findbar">
          <label for="findInput" class="toolbarLabel" data-l10n-id="find_label">Find:</label>
          <input id="findInput" class="toolbarField" tabindex="91">
          <div class="splitToolbarButton">
            <button class="toolbarButton findPrevious" title="" id="findPrevious" tabindex="92" data-l10n-id="find_previous">
              <span data-l10n-id="find_previous_label">Previous</span>
            </button>
            <div class="splitToolbarButtonSeparator"></div>
            <button class="toolbarButton findNext" title="" id="findNext" tabindex="93" data-l10n-id="find_next">
              <span data-l10n-id="find_next_label">Next</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <input type="checkbox" id="findHighlightAll" class="toolbarField" tabindex="94">
          <label for="findHighlightAll" class="toolbarLabel" data-l10n-id="find_highlight">Highlight all</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="findMatchCase" class="toolbarField" tabindex="95">
          <label for="findMatchCase" class="toolbarLabel" data-l10n-id="find_match_case_label">Match case</label>
          <span id="findResultsCount" class="toolbarLabel hidden"></span>
          <span id="findMsg" class="toolbarLabel"></span>
        </div>  <!-- findbar -->

        <div id="secondaryToolbar" class="secondaryToolbar hidden doorHangerRight">
          <div id="secondaryToolbarButtonContainer">
            <button id="secondaryPresentationMode" class="secondaryToolbarButton presentationMode visibleLargeView" title="Switch to Presentation Mode" tabindex="51" data-l10n-id="presentation_mode">
              <span data-l10n-id="presentation_mode_label">Presentation Mode</span>
            </button>

            <button id="secondaryOpenFile" class="secondaryToolbarButton openFile visibleLargeView" title="Open File" tabindex="52" data-l10n-id="open_file">
              <span data-l10n-id="open_file_label">Open</span>
            </button>

            <button id="secondaryPrint" class="secondaryToolbarButton print visibleMediumView" title="Print" tabindex="53" data-l10n-id="print">
              <span data-l10n-id="print_label">Print</span>
            </button>

            <button id="secondaryDownload" class="secondaryToolbarButton download visibleMediumView" title="Download" tabindex="54" data-l10n-id="download">
              <span data-l10n-id="download_label">Download</span>
            </button>

            <a href="#" id="secondaryViewBookmark" class="secondaryToolbarButton bookmark visibleSmallView" title="Current view (copy or open in new window)" tabindex="55" data-l10n-id="bookmark">
              <span data-l10n-id="bookmark_label">Current View</span>
            </a>

            <div class="horizontalToolbarSeparator visibleLargeView"></div>

            <button id="firstPage" class="secondaryToolbarButton firstPage" title="Go to First Page" tabindex="56" data-l10n-id="first_page">
              <span data-l10n-id="first_page_label">Go to First Page</span>
            </button>
            <button id="lastPage" class="secondaryToolbarButton lastPage" title="Go to Last Page" tabindex="57" data-l10n-id="last_page">
              <span data-l10n-id="last_page_label">Go to Last Page</span>
            </button>

            <div class="horizontalToolbarSeparator"></div>

            <button id="pageRotateCw" class="secondaryToolbarButton rotateCw" title="Rotate Clockwise" tabindex="58" data-l10n-id="page_rotate_cw">
              <span data-l10n-id="page_rotate_cw_label">Rotate Clockwise</span>
            </button>
            <button id="pageRotateCcw" class="secondaryToolbarButton rotateCcw" title="Rotate Counterclockwise" tabindex="59" data-l10n-id="page_rotate_ccw">
              <span data-l10n-id="page_rotate_ccw_label">Rotate Counterclockwise</span>
            </button>

            <div class="horizontalToolbarSeparator"></div>

            <button id="toggleHandTool" class="secondaryToolbarButton handTool" title="Enable hand tool" tabindex="60" data-l10n-id="hand_tool_enable">
              <span data-l10n-id="hand_tool_enable_label">Enable hand tool</span>
            </button>

            <div class="horizontalToolbarSeparator"></div>

            <button id="documentProperties" class="secondaryToolbarButton documentProperties" title="Document Properties…" tabindex="61" data-l10n-id="document_properties">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_label">Document Properties…</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>  <!-- secondaryToolbar -->

        <div class="toolbar">
          <div id="toolbarContainer">
            <div id="toolbarViewer">
              <div id="toolbarViewerLeft">
                <button id="sidebarToggle" class="toolbarButton" title="Toggle Sidebar" tabindex="11" data-l10n-id="toggle_sidebar">
                  <span data-l10n-id="toggle_sidebar_label">Toggle Sidebar</span>
                </button>
                <div class="toolbarButtonSpacer"></div>
                <button id="viewFind" class="toolbarButton group hiddenSmallView" title="Find in Document" tabindex="12" data-l10n-id="findbar">
                  <span data-l10n-id="findbar_label">Find</span>
                </button>
                <div class="splitToolbarButton">
                  <button class="toolbarButton pageUp" title="Previous Page" id="previous" tabindex="13" data-l10n-id="previous">
                    <span data-l10n-id="previous_label">Previous</span>
                  </button>
                  <div class="splitToolbarButtonSeparator"></div>
                  <button class="toolbarButton pageDown" title="Next Page" id="next" tabindex="14" data-l10n-id="next">
                    <span data-l10n-id="next_label">Next</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <input type="number" id="pageNumber" class="toolbarField pageNumber" title="Page" value="1" size="4" min="1" tabindex="15" data-l10n-id="page">
                <span id="numPages" class="toolbarLabel"></span>
              </div>
              <div id="toolbarViewerRight">
                <button id="presentationMode" class="toolbarButton presentationMode hiddenLargeView" title="Switch to Presentation Mode" tabindex="31" data-l10n-id="presentation_mode">
                  <span data-l10n-id="presentation_mode_label">Presentation Mode</span>
                </button>

                <button id="openFile" class="toolbarButton openFile hiddenLargeView" title="Open File" tabindex="32" data-l10n-id="open_file">
                  <span data-l10n-id="open_file_label">Open</span>
                </button>

                <button id="print" class="toolbarButton print hiddenMediumView" title="Print" tabindex="33" data-l10n-id="print">
                  <span data-l10n-id="print_label">Print</span>
                </button>

                <button id="download" class="toolbarButton download hiddenMediumView" title="Download" tabindex="34" data-l10n-id="download">
                  <span data-l10n-id="download_label">Download</span>
                </button>
                <a href="#" id="viewBookmark" class="toolbarButton bookmark hiddenSmallView" title="Current view (copy or open in new window)" tabindex="35" data-l10n-id="bookmark">
                  <span data-l10n-id="bookmark_label">Current View</span>
                </a>

                <div class="verticalToolbarSeparator hiddenSmallView"></div>

                <button id="secondaryToolbarToggle" class="toolbarButton" title="Tools" tabindex="36" data-l10n-id="tools">
                  <span data-l10n-id="tools_label">Tools</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div id="toolbarViewerMiddle">
                <div class="splitToolbarButton">
                  <button id="zoomOut" class="toolbarButton zoomOut" title="Zoom Out" tabindex="21" data-l10n-id="zoom_out">
                    <span data-l10n-id="zoom_out_label">Zoom Out</span>
                  </button>
                  <div class="splitToolbarButtonSeparator"></div>
                  <button id="zoomIn" class="toolbarButton zoomIn" title="Zoom In" tabindex="22" data-l10n-id="zoom_in">
                    <span data-l10n-id="zoom_in_label">Zoom In</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <span id="scaleSelectContainer" class="dropdownToolbarButton">
                  <select id="scaleSelect" title="Zoom" tabindex="23" data-l10n-id="zoom">
                    <option id="pageAutoOption" title="" value="auto" selected="selected" data-l10n-id="page_scale_auto">Automatic Zoom</option>
                    <option id="pageActualOption" title="" value="page-actual" data-l10n-id="page_scale_actual">Actual Size</option>
                    <option id="pageFitOption" title="" value="page-fit" data-l10n-id="page_scale_fit">Fit Page</option>
                    <option id="pageWidthOption" title="" value="page-width" data-l10n-id="page_scale_width">Full Width</option>
                    <option id="customScaleOption" title="" value="custom" disabled="disabled" hidden="true"></option>
                    <option title="" value="0.5" data-l10n-id="page_scale_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "scale": 50 }'>50%</option>
                    <option title="" value="0.75" data-l10n-id="page_scale_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "scale": 75 }'>75%</option>
                    <option title="" value="1" data-l10n-id="page_scale_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "scale": 100 }'>100%</option>
                    <option title="" value="1.25" data-l10n-id="page_scale_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "scale": 125 }'>125%</option>
                    <option title="" value="1.5" data-l10n-id="page_scale_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "scale": 150 }'>150%</option>
                    <option title="" value="2" data-l10n-id="page_scale_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "scale": 200 }'>200%</option>
                    <option title="" value="3" data-l10n-id="page_scale_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "scale": 300 }'>300%</option>
                    <option title="" value="4" data-l10n-id="page_scale_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "scale": 400 }'>400%</option>
                  </select>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="loadingBar">
              <div class="progress">
                <div class="glimmer">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div type="context" id="viewerContextMenu">
          <div id="contextFirstPage" label="First Page"
                    data-l10n-id="first_page"></div>
          <div id="contextLastPage" label="Last Page"
                    data-l10n-id="last_page"></div>
          <div id="contextPageRotateCw" label="Rotate Clockwise"
                    data-l10n-id="page_rotate_cw"></div>
          <div id="contextPageRotateCcw" label="Rotate Counter-Clockwise"
                    data-l10n-id="page_rotate_ccw"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="viewerContainer" tabindex="0" v-loading="loading">
          <div id="viewer" class="pdfViewer"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="errorWrapper" hidden='true'>
          <div id="errorMessageLeft">
            <span id="errorMessage"></span>
            <button id="errorShowMore" data-l10n-id="error_more_info">
              More Information
            </button>
            <button id="errorShowLess" data-l10n-id="error_less_info" hidden='true'>
              Less Information
            </button>
          </div>
          <div id="errorMessageRight">
            <button id="errorClose" data-l10n-id="error_close">
              Close
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="clearBoth"></div>
          <textarea id="errorMoreInfo" hidden='true' readonly="readonly"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div> <!-- mainContainer -->

      <div id="overlayContainer" class="hidden">
        <div id="passwordOverlay" class="container hidden">
          <div class="dialog">
            <div class="row">
              <p id="passwordText" data-l10n-id="password_label">Enter the password to open this PDF file:</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <!-- The type="password" attribute is set via script, to prevent warnings in Firefox for all http:// documents. -->
              <input id="password" class="toolbarField">
            </div>
            <div class="buttonRow">
              <button id="passwordCancel" class="overlayButton"><span data-l10n-id="password_cancel">Cancel</span></button>
              <button id="passwordSubmit" class="overlayButton"><span data-l10n-id="password_ok">OK</span></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="documentPropertiesOverlay" class="container hidden">
          <div class="dialog">
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_file_name">File name:</span> <p id="fileNameField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_file_size">File size:</span> <p id="fileSizeField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="separator"></div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_title">Title:</span> <p id="titleField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_author">Author:</span> <p id="authorField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_subject">Subject:</span> <p id="subjectField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_keywords">Keywords:</span> <p id="keywordsField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_creation_date">Creation Date:</span> <p id="creationDateField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_modification_date">Modification Date:</span> <p id="modificationDateField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_creator">Creator:</span> <p id="creatorField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="separator"></div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_producer">PDF Producer:</span> <p id="producerField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_version">PDF Version:</span> <p id="versionField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_page_count">Page Count:</span> <p id="pageCountField">-</p>
            </div>
            <div class="buttonRow">
              <button id="documentPropertiesClose" class="overlayButton"><span data-l10n-id="document_properties_close">Close</span></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="printServiceOverlay" class="container hidden">
          <div class="dialog">
            <div class="row">
              <span data-l10n-id="print_progress_message">Preparing document for printing…</span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <progress value="0" max="100"></progress>
              <span data-l10n-id="print_progress_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "progress": 0 }' class="relative-progress">0%</span>
            </div>
            <div class="buttonRow">
              <button id="printCancel" class="overlayButton"><span data-l10n-id="print_progress_close">Cancel</span></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  <!-- overlayContainer -->

    </div> <!-- outerContainer -->
    <div id="printContainer"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
require('pdf.js-viewer/pdf');
require('pdf.js-viewer/viewer.css');

export default
{
  props:
    {
      src:
        {
          type: String,
          required: true
        },
      filename:
        {
          type: String,
          required: true
        }
    },
  data ()
  {
    let a =
      {
        loading: false,
        timer: null
      };
    return a;
  },
  created ()
  {
    document.addEventListener('pagerendered', this.pageRendered);
  },
  beforeDestroy ()
  {
    document.removeEventListener('pagerendered', this.pageRendered);
    if (this.timer) clearInterval(this.timer);
  },
  mounted ()
  {
    this.loadFile();
  },
  watch:
    {
      src: 'loadFile'
    },
  methods:
    {
      loadFile ()
      {
        this.loading = true;
        this.timer = setInterval(this.pollPDF, 100);
        window.PDFJS.workerSrc = '/pdf.worker.js';
        if (window.PDFView.pdfDocument) window.PDFView.pdfDocument.destroy();
        window.PDFJS.webViewerLoad(this.src);
        window.PDFView.setScale('page-width', true);
      },
      pageRendered (evt)
      {
        this.loading = false;
        clearInterval(this.timer);
        this.timer = null;
      },
      pollPDF ()
      {
        if (!window.PDFView.loading) this.pageRendered();
      }
    }
}
</script>

<style>
  .pdfjs
  {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .pdfjs #scaleSelectContainer
  {
    min-width: auto !important;
    max-width: none !important;
  }

  #scaleSelect
  {
    min-width: initial !important;
  }

  .pdfjs .dropdownToolbarButton
  {
    background-image: none !important;
  }

  #toolbarViewerLeft
  {
    position: static !important;
  }

  #toolbarViewerRight
  {
    display: none !important;
  }

  #sidebarToggle
  {
    display: none;
  }

  .pdfjs #thumbnailView
  {
    width: 100% !important;
  }

  .pdfjs #errorWrapper
  {
    margin-top: 3px;
  }

  .pdfjs #errorWrapper button
  {
    color: #000;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: thank you! i have a few problems with this, which I wanted to ask you: 1. can you lock the styling from the viewer.css to only the component that contains the pdf? <style scoped> does not appear to work here. 2. when i want to open the pdf with the src prop it says "unexpected token <" in console and no pdf opens. Can i define the filename prop as whatever i want like 'this is a filename'?

Comment: The filename should be an absolute URL - not a local filesystem path. If you want to customize their CSS - you should copy the styles to the `<style scoped>` section of this component and then modify them however you need.

Comment: I tried <pdf :src="'http://cdn.mozilla.net/pdfjs/helloworld.pdf'" :filename="'http://cdn.mozilla.net/pdfjs/helloworld.pdf'"></pdf> is this wrong? My console logs: "no resource to load, early way out" and "pdf.worker.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" sry if i'm annoying you, really trying my best :/

Comment: Seems like you have not looked at the example carefully enough - there is a statement `window.PDFJS.workerSrc` which MUST point to `pdf.worker.js`. Normally you will place the file at the root of your web site. Also, it is a good practice to include the protocol (`http://` or `https://`) in the `:src` prop

Comment: thanks! Got most of it working now, it displays the right number of pages in the toolbar and also renders the pdfs inside the dom, but no page seems to show up, any idea what CSS could cause this issue?

Comment: Nope, I have no clues ... The things that you see in DOM are only the text nodes so that you can select the text from PDF. PDF itself is rendered through a CANVAS element - inside the `#viewer` DIV. I do not use this component with `scoped` styles so I do not know how it behaves in this case.

Comment: yeah, using scoped will cause some issues so i had to remove it. Also fixed the displaying of the pages, i had to remove a bottom: 32px, then everything worked well. Any idea why it only displays the first 2 pages from my 38page pdf? i get no error in the console. Also the pagenavigation does not change when scrolling to other pages or does not navogate to sites when manually changed. is that normal?

Comment: Seems like some kind of lazy-loading issue. when changing the current-page-input thing and scrolling after that it goes back to 1, if i change the zooming to 25% the third page gets rendered too, really sounds like lazy-loading

Comment: Yes, it requests the PDF using HTTP `Range` header if the server supports it.

Comment: the problem is that it doesnt request the other pages that arent loaded after the initial loading of the PDF, how would i automate that loading? alternatively disabling this range header, but the lazy loading is actually pretty cool, if it can be done easily. thanks for your great support so far dude, helping more than every other documentation i could find on pdf.js :)

Comment: You can try with `Cache Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate` on the server-side and `window.PDFJS.disableStream = true; window.PDFJS.disableAutoFetch = true;` in the client. I tried looking at 38-page PDF and it worked fine.

Comment: i tried that but i still only have the loading gifs :/ i would google the issue but as always, pdfjs has no word from this in their docs

Comment: Found out that this only happens when i set the height of the viewer element to a specific height and the element is in its viewport, when i removed the height,every page was loading correctly, but now i can't scroll again without a specified height :/ damn, pdf.js is weird.

Comment: Nevermind. I had to add the height and overflow attribute to viewerContainer and no heigth attribute at .pdfViewer. now everything works perfectly! thank you!

Comment: The viewer is designed with the presumption that it is the only thing on the page and takes full width and full height - in all other cases you have to tweak the styles. I was also forced to hide some things in the toolbar because e.g. the preview on the left was not showing thumbnails (or they were too small) and was not full height, etc.