# Embed Full Mozilla pdf.js viewer in vue.js ( using webpack via vue-cli )

Tags: javascript, pdf, vue.js, webpack, pdf.js

I would like to embed the [full Mozilla pdf.js viewer](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html) in a Vue SPA.

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51553049/how-to-use-full-pdf-js-viewer-with-toolbar-in-webpack-and-vuejs) has an accepted answer but I cannot make it work. I also get the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` error like someone in the comments.

I also found a few npm packages that seem to serve the same purpose but I couldn't make them work either:

- [pdf.js-viewer](https://github.com/legalthings/pdf.js-viewer)
- [pdfjs-dist-viewer-min](https://github.com/oci-labs/pdfjs-dist-viewer-min)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had same error and fixed it. would you try bellow?

・fixed worker's path

・disabled worker

```
window.PDFJS.workerSrc = require('pdf.js-viewer/pdf.worker');
window.PDFJS.disableWorker = true;
```