# Full-fledged PDF.js viewer in React

Tags: reactjs, next.js, pdf.js

I'm looking to use the full-featured [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) in a React component in a [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) project, as seen in Firefox and as on [this online demo](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html). Some important features here are being able to navigate to a certain page number by typing it in, and searching for text in the PDF. Is there a React component available for that?

The library [react-pdf](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf/) is nice for rendering a single page, but doesn't provide a toolbar or a convenient way of lazily loading pages in a scrollable view.

Similar to the questions [How to use full PDF.js viewer with toolbar in webpack and Vuejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51553049/how-to-use-full-pdf-js-viewer-with-toolbar-in-webpack-and-vuejs) (where the accepted answer provides a Vue component) and [Embed Full Mozilla pdf.js viewer in vue.js ( using webpack via vue-cli )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53757509/embed-full-mozilla-pdf-js-viewer-in-vue-js-using-webpack-via-vue-cli), but for React.js.

I tried including including /web/viewer.html as part of the inner HTML of a React component by doing the following, but it didn't work out.

1. Download the [latest release](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/releases/tag/v2.3.200) and extract it to a folder part of my Next.js project (which I called `pdfjs`). I tried several folders, such as /client, /client/components, /pages, /node_modules, and /.
2. Run `npm install --save-dev html-loader`
3. Use this Webpack loader that parses HTML files, by changing `next.config.js` to the following:

```js
module.exports = {
  // …
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.html$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: { loader: 'html-loader' }
    });
    return config;
  },
}
```

4. Create a simple page under /pages as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import PdfViewer from '../pdfjs/web/viewer.html'

export default function () {
  return (
    <div className="content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: PdfViewer }} />
  );
};
```

5. After running `next` in terminal to start a dev server and navigating to that page in the browser, I get an error about the JavaScript heap running out of memory.

Even if my computer had enough memory, I'm not sure that this would actually result in the PDF rendering – not to mention the danger of using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. It looks like a better solution would probably be to have an actual React component rather than trying to embed an HTML file.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf  react PDF

Comment: @jgetner yup I referred to that in my question, but it doesn't provide functionality for lazy loading a scrollable view

Comment: You can make the view scroll able.  What i think your missing is loading all pages which can be found in the recipes section of that package on github.  https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf/wiki/Recipes  what you do is render all pages and then just have a fixed height container that sets overflow:auto.   This will provide the view of the entire pdf in a scrollable view.

Comment: @jgetner The section "Display all pages" says "Please note that this approach may cause performance issues.", probably because it's not doing lazy loading and only rendering the parts of the PDF that are in view.

Comment: Ok so i tried to build in lazy loading and it just was not that great as the rendering becomes a bit clunky.  I could probably smooth it out but there is other options.  I submitted an aswer using a google embedded document viewer which i think sounds like what your sorta looking for.

Comment: @mic have u get any solutions ?

Comment: @AabirHussain Nothing beyond the answers here

Answer (score 8):

I think this might be more of what your after.  I wrapped it in a component for you already but this is a document viewer which can view PDF documents with out much work.

```
import  React,{  Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


class DocView extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render(){
        var url = "https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url="+this.props.src+"&embedded=true";
        return(
            <iframe style={this.props.style} src={url}></iframe>
        );
    }
}

export default DocView;
```

[image]

Comment: I like the idea

Comment: Nice idea to do the minimal

Comment: it is good idea but this not work in mobile browser .show plugin not installed

Answer (score 0):

[CloudPDF](https://cloudpdf.io) offers a React PDF viewer. It is basically pdf.js but then pre-rendered on the server. This gives the possibility for lazy loading of large pdf files and still keeping performance. And by default has a nice layout for the viewer.

```
import CloudPdfViewer from '@openbook/cloudpdf-viewer';

export default function () {
  return (
    <CloudPdfViewer documentId="346467a6-fa61-43ad-b45a-d1fdc3da0007" width="100%" height="500px" />
  );
};
```

[image]

Disclamer: I am working for CloudPDF and it is still a beta version.